# How to get a jsp string based array to a JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, arrays, jsp

I don't know whether what am I asking is possible or not, but I have to ask because i need a clarification on this.  I have a database table which is as follows[image]

I have a JavaScript function for dynamically adding rows which is as follows

```
function addRow() {    
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                        var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            

                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0); //create a new cell           
                        var element1 = document.createElement("input"); //create a new element           
                        element1.type = "checkbox"; //set the element type 
                        element1.setAttribute('id', 'newCheckbox'); //set the id attribute   
                        element1.setAttribute('checked',true); //set checkbox by default checked  
                        cell1.appendChild(element1); //append element to cell

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);            
                        var element2 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element2.type = "text"; 
                        element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element2.setAttribute('name', 'sl'+rowCount);
                        element2.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell2.appendChild(element2);      

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);            
                        var element3 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element3.type = "textarea"; 
                        element3.setAttribute('rows', '4');
                        element3.setAttribute('cols','40');
                        element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element3.setAttribute('name', 'discription'+rowCount);
                        cell3.appendChild(element3);         

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);            
                        var element4 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element4.type = "text"; 
                        element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element4.setAttribute('name', 'quantity'+rowCount);
                        cell4.appendChild(element4);


                        var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);            
                        var element5 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element5.type = "text"; 
                        element5.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element5.setAttribute('name', 'price'+rowCount);
                        cell5.appendChild(element5);



                        var cell6 = row.insertCell(5);            
                        var element6 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element6.type = "text"; 
                        element6.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element6.setAttribute('name', 'CST'+rowCount);
                        element6.setAttribute('style', 'width: 50px');
                        cell6.appendChild(element6);


                        var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);
                        var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
                        element7.setAttribute('multiple', '');
                        var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6','vat7','vat8','vat9'];
                        for(var i = 0;i<optarr.length;i++)
                        { 
                         var opt = document.createElement("option");
                         opt.text = optarr[i];
                         opt.value = optarr[i];
                         opt.className = optarr[i];
                         element7.appendChild(opt);
                        } 


                       element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
                       element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
                       element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');

                       cell7.appendChild(element7);
}
```

And now i have written code to get the database values and store in array.

```
<%
            Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
            String taxgroup;

            try {
                 DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                 con = db.getCon();
                 String sql = "select distinct TaxGroup from marketing_database.tax_info";
                 PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                 rs = smt.executeQuery();

                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                     taxgroup=rs.getString(1);

                        ar.add(taxgroup);
                 }
                 int size = ar.size();
                 String[] prodValues = (String[])ar.toArray(new String[ar.size()] );
                 System.out.println("size is" +size);
                 System.out.println("Names are" +Arrays.toString(prodValues));
            %>
            <%
            con.close();
            smt.close();
            rs.close();

            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }

            %>
```

Now I need to pass the array and its values to the JavaScript variable which is

```
var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6','vat7','vat8','vat9'];
```

I have to replace `['Vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6','vat7','vat8','vat9']`           with the array I wrote in the database code

Comment: Have you considered using jstl to do the exact same thing and eliminate the need to use javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do that is, create hidden field and assign value to it by jsp for example

```
<input type='hidden' name='' id='data' value=' <%= someExpressionHere  %>' />
```

Now is Js

```
document.getElementById('data').value;
```

In this way you can transfer value from jsp to the JavaScript.
In your case you want to pass array, so you can create multiple field.

```
var optarr =  ['vat1','vat2','vat3','vat4','vat5','vat6','vat7','vat8','vat9'];
```

As it have fixed column, you can create finite number of hidden field.

Comment: As you said,i am getting the value in javascript variable which is as this [Vat5.5, Vat14.5, Service]. But when i am starting a loop like for loop and giving like this for(i=0;i<optArr.length;i++).The length is showing like 27 and its 27 times looping is happening.But there are 3 words in the array.So length should be 3 but not 27.Do you have any solution for this??

Answer (score 0):

```
<%
            Connection con = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            ArrayList<String> ar=new ArrayList<String>();
            String taxgroup;


            try {
                 DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
                 con = db.getCon();
                 String sql = "select distinct TaxGroup from marketing_database.tax_info";
                 PreparedStatement smt = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                 rs = smt.executeQuery();

                 while(rs.next())
                 {
                     taxgroup=rs.getString(1);

                        ar.add(taxgroup);
                        System.out.println("Array is" +ar);
                 }
                 int size = ar.size();


                 System.out.println("size is" +size);

            %>
            <%
            con.close();
            smt.close();
            rs.close();

            }
            catch(SQLException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
              }

            %>

 var cell7 = row.insertCell(6);

          var element7 =  document.createElement("select");
          element7.setAttribute('multiple', '');
          var jsArray = [];
          <%for(int i=0;i<ar.size();i++){%>
              jsArray.push("<%= ar.get(i)%>");
          <%}%>


         //   var optarr =  ["vat1","vat2","vat3","vat4","vat5","vat6","vat7","vat8","vat9"];
          alert(jsArray.length);
          alert(jsArray);
          for(var i = 0;i<jsArray.length;i++)
          { 
           var opt = document.createElement("option");
           opt.text = jsArray[i];

           opt.value = jsArray[i];
           opt.className = jsArray[i];
           element7.appendChild(opt);
          } 
element7.setAttribute('id', 'vat5'); //set the id attribute 
         element7.setAttribute('name','tax'+rowCount);
         element7.setAttribute('value','vat5');

         cell7.appendChild(element7);
```